# How to use set to change a shell variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).

```
$ set | grep SHELL
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor:verbose
```

Now I want to change the value of the SHELL variable to /bin/dash. So I tried

```
$ set SHELL=/bin/dash
set SHELL=/bin/dash
$ set | grep SHELL
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor:verbose
_=SHELL=/bin/dash
```

I also tried several other syntax. But the SHELL variable value just doesn't change. I have two questions:

1. How to use set to change the SHELL variable
2. What is `_=SHELL=/bin/dash`?

Comment: try add `export SHELL`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`set`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin) built-in command has a number of purposes, such as turning tracing on (`set -x`) or off (`set +x`).  But it also sets the positional parameters — `$1`, `"$@"`, etc.  And that's what you've done with:

```
set SHELL=/bin/dash
echo "$1"
```

You'll get `SHELL=/bin/dash` as the output from the `echo`.

To set a variable, you set the variable — without any keywords:

```
SHELL=/bin/dash
```

The `$_` is the value of the last argument of the previous command.  For example:

```
$ cp oldfile.c newfile.c
$ vim $_
…now editing newfile.c
$
```

This can be useful, but you can also land yourself in problems because `$_` changes when you didn't expect it to.

Note that if you were misguided enough to be using a C shell or C shell derivative, then you would use `set variable=value` to set variables.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows `CMD` shell, or the Unix `csh` shells, the `set` command sets variables.

However, in Bourne-style shells such as `bash` and `dash`, you can set variables without any particular command. Setting an environment variable can be as simple as:

```
MY_VARIABLE=some_value
```

The `set` command means something quite different indeed. It's mostly useful in shell scripts, rather than in interactive shells. You use it in a shell script to set the "positional parameters" (as in first argument, second argument, etc). You can also use it to set the shell options like tracing mode (`-x`), or fail-on-error (`-E`).

Answer (score 0):

```
chsh -s {shell-name} {user-name}
```

use this if you want to change your default shell to dash

Comment: what can set really do?

Comment: It sets or unsets values of shell options and positional parameters of a shell. It doesn't change the shell itself. you can check the link for detailed description.
 [link](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/seth.html)